# Uncaught Error: no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I got an error ***no such method 'pips' for slider widget instance*** while using  jQuery UI Slider Pips. Maybe somebody knows how to fix this, it seems like script is trying to find method "pips" in wrong `JavaScript` file. Here's my header

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/slider_pips.js"></script>
```

And this is my code

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
   $("#mapslider").slider({
     value: 0,
     min: 0,
     max: 10,
     step:1,
    }).slider("pips");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved the problem by disabling async load of google maps script. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody.